# Bar charts with a image mask using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I am curious if there is a way to replicate [this type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTbPu.png) of bar chart in numpy. It is a stacked bar chart with an image overlayed such that it creates a mask around it.

Thank you!